Access to Dashboard in salesforce
I have an existing dashboard which is the default home page for the org. Users with a specific profile are not able to refresh/run the dashboard and are facing the following error
"We can't show this table because the "Viewing as" person doesn't have access to all the fields."
There is a single report that is used for the dashboard, and the users can access the report when they click on 'View Report' link.
Access has been given for the relevant fields via permission sets, would appreciate if anyone in the community has faced a similar issue before? And how to resolve this.

@kirito,
I believe this  object field has access to PortalUsers, but not able to display  dashboard components.
For display this dashboard to portal user, you should share this folder with Portal user. share the required folder with Portal users. after than it's start reflecting.

